# Open Source or free translator library / tool

Tags: machine-translation

Do you know any Open Source or free translator library / tool (English to Polish)?

Almost any language acceptable if only handled by typical Unix host (scripting, Java, C, etc.) or any tool which do not require X window.

It does not need to be grammatically correct, but that of course would be a plus.

I'm not looking for any online service like Google Translate - I'm already using Google and I need some kind of fallback.

Comment: While looking into Machine Translation for a project of mine, I came across Moses. I have never used it, but it sounds pretty cool, and is open source. feed it a library of texts translated manually between the two target languages, and it constructs a translation database on its own. It supports strict word-for-word translation and intelligent grammatical tree-based translation too. It's a C++ application, so if you want to use it on the web, you may need to write a wrapper for it in PHP or Node or your preferred server-side language with commandline capabilities. http://www.statmt.org/moses/